# Update blocked binaries after build

Tags: teamcity

I want to copy binaries to stage server as the last step of build. Previously I was doing it for asp.net web sites powered by IIS. There were no problems as IIS doesn't block any boundaries. Now I need to do the same for executable server application (it executes some background tasks) which blocks at least its exe file. So I need somehow to close application, update binaries and then run application again.

What is the best way to achieve it using TeamCity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it. I added Command Line step with following Custom Script:

```
taskkill /IM MyApplicationProcessName /F
xcopy RelativePathToBuildBinaires PathWhereToDeployBinaries /s /e /y
start PathToMyApplicationExeInDeployFolder
```

Initially it didn't work as TeamCity build agent worked as service (which do not have UI). Then I disabled service and started build agent as console (by TeamCityFolder/builagent/bin/agent.bat). And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seems like your staging server is a windows machine.  If that's the case, I'd recommend using two executables from the [PsTools Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) (PsKill and PsExec) to kill/start your process.  Here's how I would set everything up in TeamCity:

1. [Download](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip) the PsTools Suite, and copy the contents of the zip file to a folder on the build server.  I'll be using C:\Program Files\PsTools in my example.
2. Create a batch file that kills the executable server application, copies the appropriate binaries, and starts the application again.  The batch file would look something like this:

   "C:\Program Files\PsTools\PsKill" -accepteula \computername -u username -p password name_of_process_to_kill.exe

   copy files - I'm assuming you copied binaries to your ASP.Net staging site using the command line.  If not, I can provide more details later.

   "C:\Program Files\PsTools\PsExec" -accepteula \computername -u username -p password -d "path_and_name_of_executable_on_remote_server" optional_commandline_args_here
3. Add a new command line build step to your TeamCity build configuration that executes the batch file created in step #2.

I hope this helps!